# Both wifi and ethernet are gone after updating Ubuntu 20

Tags: wireless, updates, internet, ethernet, connection

After updated Ubuntu 20 I lost internet connection. Both the Wifi and Ethernet are now missing from the settings, all I see is VPN and proxy settings. ifconfig does not show the usual eth0, eno or wlan, I can only see lo:. I tried recovering but same. I recently upgraded from Ubuntu 18. I then had a problem since I uninstalled Python3 and lost the GUI. I fixed that by entering in recovery mode and reinstalling Python3 and desktop. Straight after that I installed updates and now I am unable to connect to internet. (I am posting this from my Windows machine).
Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hello. There is no such version of Ubuntu as 20. A good start to any question is an accurate version number. Nor was there ever a version 18. If you had removed python you should have done a fresh install. It is almost never 100 percent good after killing python. The help I can offer is make a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Comment: May want to check in terminal `dpkg -l | grep linux-modules-extra-$(uname -r)`

Comment: Are you asking about a Ubuntu Core 20 install??  as defaults don't match a 20 system, matching a 20.04 type of system (the *year* releases are different products to those using the *year.month* format, ie. 20 is not the same system as 20.04)

Comment: Hi all, didn't realised that. I am using Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS. I think I will reinstall. Thanks.